# What happened with the stakeholder community group the week of July 28th

Tags: discussion, stakeholder-updates

You can find previous updates of the happening of the Stakeholder group on Meta Stack Exchange [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391232/genai-previously-prompt-design-site-stakeholder-group-updates).

---

### Prompt Design Stakeholder Group Update July 28th, 2023

**Last Week**

- We put the site into a private beta. So there would be less duplicating of efforts and more of the site meta discussions would be visible
- We continue to discuss the site scope.

**This week**

- We did a [quiet launch](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/94/4) on July 25th so we could avoid last second unanticipated hiccups with the launch, and we launched publicly with an [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391667/1046749) at We Are Developers on July 26th, 2023
- We continued our many site scope and policy discussions.

**Next Week**

- You can expect more continued discussions on policy and site scope.

---

If you would like to follow along or contribute to those discussions, you can some, but not all, here:

- [Are questions around Jail Breaking Generative AI tools on topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/are-questions-around-jail-breaking-generative-ai-tools-on-topic)
- [How to judge if a question is asking the off-topic "ready-to-go" prompt?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-judge-if-a-question-is-asking-the-off-topic-ready-to-go-prompt)
- [Do we want an image of the week competition?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/do-we-want-an-image-of-the-week-competition)
- [We are still looking to define the tone and quality standards of GenAI SE among other critical attributes](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/we-are-still-looking-to-define-the-tone-and-quality-standards-of-genai-se-among)
- [Is it okay to ask for examples of genAI usage and output?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-examples-of-genai-usage-and-output)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the "question", there are several on-going discussions about the site scope and rules:

#### [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope) 17 questions

- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) : [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/genai-se?cb=1)
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) :  [Are questions around Jail Breaking Generative AI tools on topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/)

#### [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) 3 questions

- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) : [Is it acceptable to post AI-generated answers?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/806)

#### [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)

There is only one question using this tag [What are the best practices to have debates in GenAI Meta?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/)

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

There are 8 questions with this tag that haven't a status tag yet.

#### [private-beta](/questions/tagged/private-beta)

During the private beta we had lower thresholds, but they were changed to the default thresholds for public-betas that might need to be revisited, like:

- [Do we want that new users (rep 1) be able to post in GenAI SE Meta without having to post to the main site first?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/57/806)